# Há um ganho de performance em concatenar strings diretamente no SQL?

Tags: javascript, sql, node.js, postgresql, desempenho

Atualmente, eu tenho um código mais ou menos assim:

```js
const users = await query(`
  SELECT "id", "username", "email" FROM "users";
`)
  .then((users) => users.map((user) => {
    user.id = btoa(`user:${user.id}`);
    return user;
  });
```

O objetivo disso é converter todos os IDs sequenciais e numéricos (que eu preciso no banco de dados) em IDs que contém o nome da  entidade em um formato de *string*, para que possam ser consumidos pelo cliente, de modo a não existirem colisões no cache dos usuários.

Nesse contexto, recentemente, fiquei pensando se poderia tornar esse tipo de operação mais performática, já que deve ser feita **sempre** que qualquer entidade, de qualquer tabela, for enviado ao cliente.

Uma outra alternativa seria realizar essa codificação diretamente através do `SELECT`, mais ou menos assim:

```sql
SELECT
  encode(concat('user:', "id")::bytea, 'base64') as "id",
  "username",
  "email"
FROM "users";
```

Esse tipo de operação seria mais performático que fazê-lo diretamente no Node.js?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Primeiro tenho que dizer que essas coisas não são fáceis de definir assim, não é algo que pode ser facilmente inferido, só testando para saber.

Segundo, precisa ver se precisa mesmo dessa performance, fazer algo que não traga vantagens clara não vale o esforço. Essa parece ser uma mudança mínima que não vai mudar quase nada.

Terceiro, eu acho que se existem outras soluções que podem dar resultado bem melhor, por exemplo manter cache de dados no cliente, ou mesmo não usar web que limita o que pode ser feito ou mesmo porque a linguagem escolhida não é ideal para performance. E digo isto porque trocar de linguagem causará um impacto absurdamente maior que fazer essa mudança, só para dar um parâmetro de como é irrelevante onde está concatenando o dado. E mais, se esse nível de ganho é necessário o código deveria ser menos abstrato e usar mecanismos puros que permitem uma performance melhor do que está usando. Em geral não faz diferença, mas faz mais que mudar a concatenação de lugar.

Seria diferente se você estivesse trafegando um monte de informação para o cliente e muita coisa seria descartada.

Já testou se esse `await` está ajudando ou atrapalhando? Eu vejo muita gente começar usar isso porque leram em algum lugar que é legal e vi muita gente ter resultados piores porque ao contrário da crença popular ele é mais lento que fazer síncrono, a diferença é que ele não bloqueia a aplicação quando está rodando algo assíncrono, embora o `await`, como o  nome diz, fica esperando. Existe ganhos em alguns casos não em todos.

Em uma operação assim ocorre uma quantidade enorme de atividade computacional envolvendo inclusive hardware bem mais lento, então a concatenação é "cosquinha" no todo, principalmente do jeito que está escrito.

Eu chutaria que por tudo isso terá um ganho ínfimo se fizer no banco de dados, mas depende de muita coisa, inclusive pode ir melhor em um cenário e não em outro diferente deste, ou mudar no futuro de acordo com a versão do Node ou do PostgreSQL que está usando. No fim só testando no seu seu cenário real, nem vale se fizer um teste em ambiente diferente do que vai rodar de verdade (mesma carga e dados inclusive).

Existem alguns tipos de operação que o banco de dados pode ser muito mais performático. Existem alguns raros casos que fazer no cliente pode ser mais rápido, embora fazer no cliente pode ser mais útil para reduzir complexidade da *query*, desde que ela não trafega mais dados por causa disto.